# imagecopy PHP for progress bar doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a problem making the `imagecopy` function work in PHP.

I don't even know where to start debugging; images is a new fruit for me.

Portion where I have problem:

```
imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
        imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($pbuble), imagesy($pbuble));
```

Full code (my plan is first to copy on top of `$png <- $bgr <- $pbuble`):

```
<?php
//Check for correct GET variables
if (is_numeric($_GET['max']) AND is_numeric($_GET['val'])) {
    $max = $_GET['max'];
    $val = $_GET['val'];
} else {return false;}

    //Create empty placeholder
    $png = imagecreate(380, 37);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($png, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($png, $black);

    //Create background image with transparency
    $bgr = imagecreatefrompng("progress-bgr.png");
        imageAlphaBlending($bgr, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($bgr, true);

    //Calculate width of progress bar atm
        $width = imagesx($bgr);
        $height = imagesy($bgr);

    $pb_width = $val * $width / $max;

    //Percentage buble
    $pbuble = imagecreatefrompng("percentage-bubble.png");
        imageAlphaBlending($pbuble, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($pbuble, true);

        $perct = $val * 100 / $max;
        $txt = $perct . "%";
        $txt_color = imagecolorallocate($pbuble, 255, 255, 255);
        $font = "dejavusans-webfont.ttf";
        $font_size = 7;

        $bbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $txt);

        $x = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($pbuble) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2);
        //$y = $bbox[1] + (imagesy($pbuble) / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2);

    imagettftext($pbuble, $font_size, 0, $x, 14, $txt_color, $font, $txt);

    //
    imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($pbuble), imagesy($pbuble));


//Output image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($png);
//
imagedestroy($png);
imagedestroy($bgr);
imagedestroy($pbuble);
?>
```

Comment: What *do* you get? errors? nothing? black image? white image? what?

Comment: What is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: Please post all shown errors when asking a question here.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't see merged element, I see transparent png.

Comment: @Mooseman There are no errors.

Comment: @alexn It just shows bgr image with transparency. I don't see $bgr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me :)

```
imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

has two extra parameters.
should be:

```
imagecopy($png, $bgr, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```